# How to create Video playlist in Python 2.7 using vlc

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I want to create a video playlist in python using vlc. The videos are in my local drive. Currently, I'm using Python 2.7. vlc & cv2 is working fine.

Result: vlc should play all videos in sequence in that playlist and at the end of the last video it should repeat the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Googling "VLC Python" returned some quite good tutorials. This would provide a better learning experience as the code snippets will be explained.

```
import vlc

playlist = ['/path/to/song1.flac', '/path/to/song2.flac', 'path/to/song3.flac']

while True:
    for song in playlist:
        player = vlc.MediaPlayer(song)
        player.play()
```

Comment: I have tried it unfortunately its giving error :  "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'". Plz. help.

Comment: Can you post your playlist line?

Comment: playlist = [ 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Work\\FramesetVideos\\Colgate.mp4' ,'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Work\\FramesetVideos\\HeroPassion.mp4' ]